# JQ filter file input under windows

Tags: jq

I actually use jq (1.5) with Windows 10 to Format different json files. I tried today to move the filters to a filter file to cut the length of my cmd commands.
I copied the filter directly from the command with all Quotations but i received an Syntax error. I tried to remove the qotations or Change them to ' but i still receive the Syntax error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

[.cruises[] | { nid: .cruise_nid, shipcategory: .ship_category, ship: .ship_title, company: .company_title, includeflight: .includes_flight, nights, waypoints: .waypoint_cities, title: .route_title}] C:\import\dreamlines_cruises.json > C:\Import\import_cruises.json

Any tips?

Regards Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jq filter as given (i.e. without quotation marks) looks fine, so let's assume you have successfully placed the text (hopefully formatted for readability :-) in a file, say format.jq

Then you would run something like this:

```
jq -f format.jq dreamlines_cruises.json
```

Comment: Hi Peak, thanks for your Input. I found my mistake. I placed in the file the complete command (including file Input/Output). Without that with only the filter it works like a charm. Thanks. Regards Timo